# Launching image picker is slow the first time

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, ipad

Is it normal for the imagepicker to take a while to load the photo album the first time and subsequent views are fast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed that in my testing as well.  It doesn't surprise me, iOS probably keeps the imagepicker in memory once it has created and initialized it.